# Ajax function call not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to learn Ajax function calls in jquery. But I could not get the expected output. My code is below

The HTML and Script File is stored in the file 'addevent.php'

HTML Code:

```
<form id="addinfo">
Year: <div class="styled-select">
<select id="year">
<option>2017</option><option>2018</option>
<option>2019</option><option>2020</option>
</select>
</div>

Team:<div class="styled-select">
<select id="team">
<option>UG</option><option>PG</option>
</select>
</div>
<button class=btn name="add_event" id="add_event" />Add Event
<span id="result"></span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Script Part:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){      
    $("#add_event").click(function(){  
        var y= $("#year option:selected").text();
        var t= $("#team option:selected").text();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkevent.php', 
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {year:y , team: t},  
            success: function(result) {  
                console.log(result);
                var val=result['result'];
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=val;
            }
            error: function(exception) {
                alert('Exeption:'+exception);
            }
        });
    });  
});
</script>
```

The code in the file checkevent.php is below

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=register;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$year =$_POST['year'];
$team =$_POST['team'];
$table=$team.$year;
try
{
    if ($db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $table . "'")->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $r=array("result"=>"already stored");
        echo json_encode($r);
    }
    else
    {
        $r=array("result"=>"continue");
        echo json_encode($r);
    }   
}//end of try
catch(PDOException $e) 
{
    $r=array("result"=>"error");
    echo json_encode($r);
}//end of catch
?>
```

Please Note: I have stored the file 'addevent.php' (HTML+Script) in the location 'registration/view/'

The checkevent.php file is stored in the location 'registration'

I tried to check if the button click function for add_event button is working by placing an alert inside it. But it doesn't work.

My expected output is if the table exist the span should display 'already stored' else it should say 'continue'

P.S: I am new to using these ajax call,so sorry if this seems silly. Please help to understand these concepts clearly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use developer tools to see what happening with you script. Does the ajax call ever take place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change this line :

```
     url: 'checkevent.php',
```

By this :

```
     url: '../checkevent.php',
```

Type F12 and inspect your ajax Call in the console to see if everything is OK

Comment: Noted this mistake. Changed the URL but still could not get it working.. I will continue checking it.. If you could help more, please do...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

OK got it. You missed a comma between success and error callbacks, which broke your Javascript...

Please change script to this and it should work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){      
        $("#add_event").click(function(){  
            var y= $("#year option:selected").text();
            var t= $("#team option:selected").text();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/registration/checkevent.php', 
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {year:y , team: t},  
                success: function(result) {  
                    console.log(result);
                    var val=result['result'];
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=val;
                },
                error: function(exception) {
                    alert('Exeption:'+exception);
                }
            });
        });  
    });
</script>
```

---

You have a `<button>` element inside a form. The default type of a button is `type="submit"` and therefore the form is submitted before the button onclick listener works. Also you need to close a button element with `</button>`

Try to change it from

```
<button class=btn name="add_event" id="add_event" />Add Event
```

to

```
<button type="button" class=btn name="add_event" id="add_event" >Add Event</button>
```

As for the ajax URL, if you are running it from a page located in 'registration/view' and you're calling a page located in 'registration', you need to change the url to something like:
 `url: '/registration/checkevent.php'`

because the php file isn't located in the same place as the script that's calling it.

Good luck

Comment: Noted the Mistake in Button and changed it. But still could not get the expected output. BTW thanks for your help.. Cool!!

Comment: Nope it isn't working. I wrote an alert code directly after entering on_click but it's still not working. If I remove the ajax call code from on_click() and place only the alert code inside, it works fine. But if the ajax call code follows the alert, the alert is not working.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I tested and works for me

Comment: Yep got it now. The comma was the exact mistake and now it works perfectly. Thanks....